# После установки библиотеки kivy через cmd ошибка с библиотекой. Помогите плиз

Tags: python, kivy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот пример если навести на одну из строк где написано киви.(пишу в вс код)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите пожалуйста, может нужно обновить пип или ещё что-то.

буду рад любой помощи

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас переделаю текстом

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать переустановить `kivy`:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall kivy
```

А `pip` можно обновить такой командой, но если нужно будет обновить он сам тебе напишет как это сделать и приложит команду.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: попробовал первую команду выдало ошибку : "pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. уже даже не знаю что делать, питон стоит версии 3.7.9, винда новая, никаких ошибок не должно быть, всё устанавливалось успешно. может есть ещё какие-то варианты? БУДУ БЛАГОДАРЕН ЛЮБОМУ

Comment: Так у вас не установлен пакетный менеджер pip. А это надо переустанавливать Python

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, позже вернусь

Comment: вообщем переустановил питон, попробовал скачать библиотеку телеграмма, всё хорошо, она установилась, после попробовал скачать библиотеку киви она выдал в конце ошибку чтобы обновить версию пип, я прописал команду, пип обновился до последней версии, после попробовал установить киви, но в конце она уже выдала другую ошибку : × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.                                       что-то типо этого

Comment: Узнал, что kivy не работает с Python 3.11 он хорошо работает с Python 3.10.8

Comment: Еще почитал, что надо установить зависимости, о которых можно узнать на официальном сайте kivy

Comment: Леонид, спасибо, попробую, позже отпишу.